# Can i fork this code from gist and using it for my own projects?

Tags: github, gist, git-fork

Hello I'm new to Github/Gist and I want to use this code, but I need to modify it a little bit. Can i just fork this code and modify it to use it for my own projects? Or do i have to link to the author etc.? Here is the link: https://gist.github.com/learncodeacademy/777349747d8382bfb722

Thank you!

Comment: when you are using a forked repository.It shows up as "forked from xyz". So attribution is automatic.

Answer (score 0):

`Github` repositories are *meant* to be forked.  You don't have to ask an author for permission. Anyway, the gist you linked to has already been forked [30 times](https://gist.github.com/learncodeacademy/777349747d8382bfb722/forks).

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a forked repository.It shows up as "forked from xyz". So attribution is automatic. But if you want to, you can always give an extra credit to the author by mentioning it specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Forking a repository on Github, creates an individual copy of the code. This feature is meant to encourage collaboration as well as allow you to experiment with the repositories code. Forking can be used to propose new changes to someone else's code or jumpstart an idea or a new project. As the repository was created by someone else, it is always important to understand the limitations of using their code for your own projects (especially if you plan on selling this product). Every repository created on Github has the chance to create a license file. This file will tell you what you can or cannot do with the forked code. Often open source code is meant to be used and shared with everyone, but it is still good to check. Here is Githubs documentation on forking repositories: https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/. For more information on licensing files see http://choosealicense.com/. Github gists follow the same standard. If you are still worried, it does not hurt to contact the owner of the repository and verify that you can use it for your own projects.

Answer (score 0):

The point of open sourcing code on GitHub is for others to take and use for themselves and learn from it. Also, like fuchsteufelswild said, when forking on GitHub it automatically gives credit to the author so you should be good.